# How to plot circles in trading view with for loop using pine code

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to use square numbers gann square of 9 logic, for that i am trying to plot lines or circles
with the for loop

but when i am trying  getting this error  `Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.`

Please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The function `plot` can't be used inside loops, however, this isn't the case for `line.new` or `label.new`, you can try using these functions instead.

Comment: can u please provide an example.